Parametric plot issue
I have a simple program,
pr = (8*M*r^2 - 3*Pi^2*\[Alpha]*r^2 - 3*Pi^2*r^4 - 4*Q^2)/(4*Pi^3*r^6); 
tm = (16*M*r^2 - 6*Pi^2*\[Alpha]*r^2 - 3*Pi^2*r^4 - 12*Q^2)/(6*Pi^3*r^3*(2*\[Alpha] + r^2))
Q = Sqrt[3]*Pi; M = 7; \[Alpha] = 0.2;
ParametricPlot[{pr, tm}, {r, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.2}, {0, 0.2}}, AspectRatio -> 1

Basically I want to plot tm vs pr. But this code is not giving me the desired result. The figure should look like This,

Is there anything wrong in my code or the plot was done using something other than parametric plot?
Duplicate- here
Thanks in advance.

You have to check the expressions pr,tm. Your expressions Asymptotic[{pr, tm}, r -> 0]  are singular {-(3/(\[Pi] r^6)), -(4.77465/r^3)} at r->0!

even if I plot for {r,1,10}, it does not change a thing. I am actually getting a result. But it does not match with diagram given here.

My comment only shows that the result can't match the diagram! Where did you get the expressions pr,tm from? Are you sure that this source gives correct expressions?

Yes, I got the expression from a paper and I myself have calculated them. the expressions are correct.

The expressions cannot be correct, because in addition to my arguments  pr[r]<0,tm[r]<0 both are negative for r>0 (see answer in your duplicate question)

okay, I am checking again.

First, pr and tm are no defined for r==0.
Then neither pr nor tm depend on Q.
Further, if you plot pr against tm, you get:
ParametricPlot[{pr, tm}, {r, 1, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]


Therefore, I guess your formula for pr and/or tm is wrong.
